# WP7 Silverlight -- tapping image in a stackpanel scrollview to show that same picture in another grid

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, grid, imagesource

I am probably the absolute worst "coder" trying to create a Windows Phone 7 app, but I am in dire need of help, and some of you may even consider it to be laughably easy (which it probably is).

My problem: How on earth do I code the tapping of a picture from one grid to display as a bigger image on another grid?

And I'll elaborate:

I have an app page (in landscape mode only), with two grids splitting the screen.

The first grid (`smallgrid`) contains a Scrollviewer (`small`) with a Stackpanel (`smallimages`) of images reduced to 1/10 of their size within it, essentially showing thumbnails of images.

The second grid (`contentgrid`) is designed where once you tap on a thumbnail image from `smallgrid` that image will be shown in `contentgrid`

By default, balloon0 is displayed in the `contentgrid` and will change when a person taps on one of the smaller images.

I'll try to provide some mock code for this:

```
<grid x:name="smallgrid">
  <scrollviewer x:name="small">
    <stackpanel x:name="smallimages">
      <image="balloon0.jpg"><image>
      <image="balloon1.jpg"><image>
      <image="balloon2.jpg"><image>
      <image="balloon3.jpg"><image>
    </stackpanel>
  </scrollviewer>
</grid>

<grid x:name="contentgrid">
  <image source="balloon0.jpg"><image>
</grid>
```

The code behind is where I need help. I am thinking I either use a button that once clicked, that image then replaces the image in `contentgrid` but I have no idea how to do that.

Or I can use a gesturelistener that when an image is tapped, it will replace the image in `contentgrid`... but I also don't know how to do that.

Any insight is helpful. Thank you for any help, as I am not a C# coder, let alone know the language or WP7 silverlight too well.

Comment: I briefly saw your "answer" where you elaborated on a further problem you were having.  I went to edit your question to place it there and in the meantime someone deleted it.  You can always edit your original question to add further details/problems (obviously non-answers will get deleted).  As for your problem, if you could update your question and include some more detail (show the actual XAML you are using for instance) I or someone else will probably be able to help you further. FUN FUN FUN!

Comment: Ok. When I'm home I'll be able to upload the XAML and edit my question with the additional problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to add the Silverlight Toolkit assembly reference to your phoneapplicationpage element (and as a reference to the project):

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

You can use the GestureListener from the Silverlight Toolkit in your XAML like this (also be sure to add the name property to your large image):

```
<grid x:name="smallgrid">
   <scrollviewer x:name="small">
      <stackpanel x:name="smallimages">
         <image="balloon0.jpg">
           <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
             <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="smallImage_Tap" />
           </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
         <image>
         <image="balloon1.jpg">
           <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
             <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="smallImage_Tap" />
           </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
         <image>
         <image="balloon2.jpg">
           <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
             <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="smallImage_Tap" />
           </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
         <image>
         <image="balloon3.jpg">
           <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
             <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="smallImage_Tap" />
           </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
         <image>
      </stackpanel>
   </scrollviewer>
</grid>

<grid x:name="contentgrid">
   <image x:Name="BigImage" source="balloon0.jpg"><image>
</grid>
```

Then in your code-behind you can handle the event like this:

```
private void smallImage_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    BigImage.Source = (sender as Image).Source;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the toolkit source code, then it appears that GestureListener.Tap event is generated whenever XNA TouchPanel detects Tap gesture. Intuitively I would expect that this happens whenever MouseLeftButtonUp event is generated. Ok, not always, but in the described type of interaction it is basically "always".

Hence I feel both these levels (XNA and Toolkit classes) as unnecessary overhead - at least for something as simple as the tap event. (Other negative consequences: App size increases as you have to include the toolkit, slower launching as more assemblies have to be loaded.)

Having said that, I would start by simply listening to MouseLeftButtonUp event as for example

```
<Image Source="123.jpg" MouseLeftButtonUp="smallImage_Tap" ImageOpened="..." ImageFailed="..."/>
```

I included also ImageOpened/Failed events. You can optionally use them to fine tune your app. They could solve problems such as too frequent tap events or image load failures.

Comment: Thank you for this, and I'll play around with it too. I haven't had the chance to even open the app since leaving my last comment a few days ago.